# C++ Simplifying Code

Tags: c++

I just had a basic question. Is this possible to simplify any further, because I call this same thing pretty much for a sin cos tan asin acos and atan. It just looks ugly and I want to make it look pretty if possible.

```
if(m_RHS->get_gType() == INT)
    {
        ostringstream ss;
        ss << (sin(m_RHS->evalint() * (M_PI / 180)));
        return ss.str();
    }
else
    {
        ostringstream ss;
        ss << (sin(m_RHS->evaldouble() * (M_PI / 180)));
        return ss.str();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metaprogramming, fo' shizzle:

```
template<typename T>
std::string sin_deg_str(T angle_deg)
{
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << (sin(angle_deg * (M_PI / 180)));
    return ss.str();
}

// ...

if(m_RHS->get_gType() == INT)
    return sin_deg_str(m_RHS->evalint());
else
    return sin_deg_str(m_RHS->evaldouble());
```

Not sure you could eliminate the `if...then` with a `?:` operator, though, since the types don't match.

---

Adding more functions? This might work:

```
template<typename T, typename Function>
std::string call_deg_str(T angle_deg)
{
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << (Function(angle_deg * (M_PI / 180)));
    return ss.str();
}

// ...

if(m_RHS->get_gType() == INT)
    return call_deg_str<sin>(m_RHS->evalint());
else
    return call_deg_str<sin>(m_RHS->evaldouble());
```

Comment: Oh this looks fun.  I might give this a shot.

Comment: I tried this way I'm getting a few errors. I've never used templated functions before so its a bit of a learning curve. The template is declared in the .h file only is what I have read. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's just in the .h file.

Comment: I seem to be have the problem where it does not recognize the templated function in my .cpp file.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try this:

```
ostringstream ss;
double val;

if (m_RHS->get_gType() == INT){
    val = m_RHS->evalint();
} else {
    val = m_RHS->evaldouble();
}

ss << sin(val * (M_PI / 180));
return ss.str();
```

Notice that I used a `double` as the type for val, because you can store an integer in a double, but not the other way around (without truncating).

Or for compactness (but sacrificing readability):

```
ostringstream ss;
ss << sin((m_RHS->get_gType() == INT ? m_RHS->evalint() : m_RHS->evaldouble()) * (M_PI / 180));
return ss.str();
```

Comment: I see how that is shorter, but if I wanted to add cos, tan, asin, acos, atan, I don't think this implementation would work. I could be horribly wrong.

Comment: In that case, can you show an example of the (currently ugly) implementation using cos, tan, etc.? You can probably use function pointers to simplify it (http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/)

Comment: Was a smidgen long for a comment so I put it here.

**[My Code](http://pastebin.com/PMUkWkTG)**

Comment: Your case blocks lack `break;` statements.

Comment: The way to simplify it, following the "cast to `double`" strategy you outlined, is to split the code into two phases. First, convert the value to a `double`. Second, call the appropriate trig function.

Answer (score 1):

```
ostringstream ss;
if(m_RHS->get_gType() == INT)
   ss << (sin(m_RHS->evalint() * (M_PI / 180)));
else
   ss << (sin(m_RHS->evaldouble() * (M_PI / 180)));
return ss.str();
```

this is the most sipliest